# Groups in the generalized triple "semidirect" product of semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, semidirect-product

A semigroup $S$ acts on another semigroup $V$ (written additively for better readability, but could be non-commutative) on the left if
$$
 s(v_1 + v_2) = sv_1 + s v_2, \quad
 s(s')v = (ss')v
$$
for $s,s' \in S, v,v_1,v_2\in V$. Similar a right action is given by the laws $(v_1 + v_2)s = v_1s + v_2s$ and $(vs)s' = v(ss')$.

Suppose we have three semigroups $S,T,V$ such that $S$ acts on $V$ on the left, and $T$ on the right, and such that both action are compatible in the sense that we have
$$
 (sv)t = s(vt)
$$
for $s \in S, t \in T, v \in V$. Then we define the triple "semi-direct" product $(T,V,S)$ as the set of all triples $(t,v,s)$ with multiplication 
$$
 (t,v,s)(t',v',v') = (tt', vt' + sv', ss').
$$

I have a question on the following proof:

> Let $G$ be a group in $(T,V,S)$. There exists then an invariant (=normal) subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $H$ is isomorphic with a group in $V$ while $G/H$ is isomorphic with a group in $T \times S$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $(c,d,e)$ be the unit element of $G$. Then $c$ is an idempotent in $T$ and $e$ is an idempotent in $S$. Define
>   $$
>  H = \{(c,v,e) \mid (c,v,e) \in G \}.
> $$
>   Clearly $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and is the kernel of the morphism $\varphi : G \to T\times S$ given by $\varphi(s,v,t) = (s,t)$. Thus $G/H$ is isomorphic with a group in $T \times S$. To show that $H$ is isomorphic with a group in $V$ we define $\psi : H \to V$ by setting
>   $$
>  \psi(c,v,e) = evc.
> $$
>   We have
>   \begin{align*}
>  \psi[(c,v,e)(c,v',e)] & = \psi(c,vc + ev', e) \\ 
>                        & = e(vc + ev')c = evc + ev'c \\
>                        & = \psi((c,v,e)) + \psi((c,v',e))
> \end{align*}
>   so that $\psi$ is a morphim. Since
>   \begin{align*}
>  (c,v,e) & = (c,d,e)(c,v,e)(c,d,e) \\
>          & = (c,dc + evc + ed,e)
> \end{align*}
>   it follows that $\psi$ is injective. Thus $\psi$ maps $H$ isomorphically onto a group in $V$. $\square$

I do not understand the last step, in reasoning that $\psi$ is injective? It is just rewritten $(c,v,e)$ with the idenity $(c,d,e)$. As the image of $\psi$ is a group, the kernel in this case is the inverse image of the idenity, which is $edc$. Hence what we should compute is
$$
 \psi(c,v,e) = edv
$$
which is equivalent with $evc = edv$. But I do not see how to go on from here, and what this has to do with the given computations? (Similar showing $evd = ev'd$ implies $v = v'$ I am not able to derive...)

Could anyone please explain what is happening here?

Remark: The statement is taken from page 145 of [Samuel Eilenberg, Automata, Languages, and Machines, Vol. B](https://books.google.de/books?id=YkuXEJ34xF0C&pg=PA109&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\psi(c,v,e) = \psi(c,d,e)$, that is, $evc = edc$. Then
$$
  (c,v,e) = (c,dc+evc+ed,e) = (c,dc+edc+ed,e) = (c,d,e)
$$